# Is it possible to auto paste and click a button in the website by chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a two steps operation on a video URL by using chrome extension. First, paste the URL to another website's textbox.(For example, https://www.urlgot.com/). And then click the "search" button. Could I do it automatically by chrome extension? Is this operation allowed by chrome? I got a list of URLs of video and corresponding captions to download. So I want to do it automatically by calling related websites. I just wonder these could be done by chrome extension. 
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Your extension will need a *content script* to access the web page. Then it's a rather trivial DOM operation so yeah it's possible, but the question is too broad as it comprises the basics of DOM and the extension architecture. Break down the task into parts and look for examples for each one.

Comment: @wOxxOm Now I only want to do the paste and click steps. I will try to use content script as you said. But I am new in Chrome scripting. Could you give me some hints or sketch about script? It is a pitty that I could not accept your advice as an answer. Thank you!